# Why does sympy not think my constant is real?

Tags: python, sympy, physics

I am running this code:

```
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()
from IPython.display import display_latex
a = sym.symbols('a', real = True)
r = sym.symbols('r', real = True)

wavefunction = sym.exp(-a*r**2)
normalization_squared = 4*sym.pi*sym.integrate((r**2)*wavefunction**2, (r, 0, sym.oo))
display_latex(normalization_squared.simplify())
```

and get this result:

[image: latex]

I am surprised that it has an "if arg(z)<pi/2" as I have explicitly told it that a and r are real? What gives?

I have tried adding "sym.assumptions.assume.global_assumptions.add(sym.Q.real(a))" but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `arg` condition that you see is a way of saying that the real part of `a` should be positive. That is because the meijerg algorithm deals with angular regions of the complex plane. Declaring `a` to be real does not imply that its real part is positive.

Your integral is:

```
In [3]: 4*sym.pi*sym.Integral((r**2)*wavefunction**2, (r, 0, sym.oo))
Out[3]:
    ∞
    ⌠
    ⎮           2
    ⎮  2  -2⋅a⋅r
4⋅π⋅⎮ r ⋅ℯ        dr
    ⌡
    0
```

This integral does not converge for negative `a`. If you declare `a` to be positive (`symbols('a', positive = True)`) then you will get the expected result:

```
In [5]: normalization_squared
Out[5]:
    3/2
√2⋅π
───────
   3/2
4⋅a
```